# what is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!\log n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!\log n!}$ converging? I tried numerically and I think that it is, but to what? and how to show it?

Comment: Note for $n = 1$ that $n! = 1$ and $\log 1 = 0$.

Comment: i think you should prove from 2 to infinity , and you can prove by induction after n=4 $\frac{1}{n!}<\frac{1}{n^2}$ . Even series of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges so it would definately converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can apply comparison test and see that, for $n > 2$:
$$
\frac{1}{n!\log{n!}} < \frac{1}{n!}
$$
It's a well-known fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e$ converges. Since all the terms in the series are positive, the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing Clement's answer, to compute the sum of the series, I think you have to do it numerically, but this is easy.

For example, $$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n!\log{n!}}=\sum_{n=2}^9\frac1{n!\log{n!}}+\sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac1{n!\log{n!}}
$$
If we take the first term on the right-hand side as an approximation, then the error is $$
\sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac1{n!\log{n!}}<\frac1{\log10!}\sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac1{n!}
$$
The sum on the right-hand side is the truncation error in approximating $e^x$ at $x=1$ by the ninth-degree Taylor polynomial, so by Taylor's theorem with remainder it does not exceed $\frac{e}{10!}$ and the error is less than $$\frac{e}{10!\log10!} \approx4.95910^{-8}\cdot$$

Just decide what accuracy you want, and figure out how many terms of the series you need to sum in order to achieve it.

**NOTE**

I assume you really want the series to start at $n=2$, since as others have pointed out, the $n=1$ term is undefined.