# what is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n!}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

what is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n!}{n!}$ converging to? related to [what is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!\log n!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538770/what-is-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-log-n/3538791#3538791) (can I use the same methods?)

I'm pretty sure it converges to somewhere between -1 and -2, as the partial sum of the first 40 elements is -1.2 and so is the sum of the first 80 elements...

Comment: What have you done so far?  Do you think it converges or diverges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use similar methods on this problem.  Notice that $\log1!=\log1 = 0$, so we might as well start at $n=2$.

We have $$\log n!=\log1 + \log2+\cdots+\log n <n\log n$$ so $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\log n!}{n!}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\log n}{(n-1)!}$$  When $n > 1$ we have $\log n<n-1$ so $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\log n!}{n!}<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{(n-2)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}$$ and the series on the right is the convergent series for $e$.

You can compute the sum numerically in much the same way as I described in the previous question.